# Strange sizeof(std::map)

Tags: c++, stdmap

I'm using std::map, and can't understand how much memory it consumes.

I have the following map definitions:

```
CKey {
 long x;
 int y;
 int z;
 bool operator<(const CKey& l) const;
};

CValue {
 int data1;
 int data2;
}

std::map<CKey, CValue> map;
std::cout << "sizeof() = " << sizeof(map) << " Max #Elms = " << map.max_size();
```

(No mater before or after inserting elements into the map)
I'm getting that.

```
sizeof() = 48
Max_Size = 329406144173384850
```

1. If `sizeof(map) = 48`, how can it contains `329406144173384850` elements ?
2. Does the map save the `<CKey,Cvalue>` in other memory (heap ?)

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/max_size `max_size` will give you the maximum number of element you may put in the map given your current system, not the number of pairs that are in the map.

Comment: The `sizeof` operator returns the size of the *object*, not the data it contains. It's simply a sum of the `sizeof` of all members (plus potential padding). It's like doing `sizeof(some_pointer)`, which returns the size of the *pointer*, and not the size of the data pointed to.

Comment: MaxSize is not what you think, and Sizeof is also not what you think. RTFM for all's sake instead of guessing just by their name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++ sizeof() of a class with functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552319/c-sizeof-of-a-class-with-functions)  -- it is not "exact duplicate" since it asks about a "class with functions" but it's hard to deny that a std::map is a class, and that it has methods.

Comment: Instead of `sizeof(map)` you need `map.size()`.

Comment: hm... however, to be fair, I have to give it a plus, since in fact this is one of the better-formulated questions asking about `sizeof`. Good job, seriously!

Comment: Oh, one more thing, the "consumption of memory" may be hard to determine. Map is not a simple array, knowing how many elements (see RustyX's comment) won't tell you much more than just general idea of the order of magnitude. map of 4-byte int with 10^6 elements will take much more than 4mb of memory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C and C++, the `sizeof` operator tells you how many bytes of *stack* space an instance of the class will occupy.

Like the other standard containers (except `std::array`), `map` allocates its elements on the *heap* when using the default allocator. This means that its static size (i.e. what `sizeof` returns) does not depend on the number of elements in the `map`.

You can find out how many elements are in a `map` using the `size()` member function. The `max_size()` member function on the other hand tells you how many elements the `map` could theoretically store -- on a 64-bit system, you are almost certainly going to be limited by the amount of RAM on your system rather than what `max_size()` returns.

Actually working out the total memory use (stack and heap) of a `map` is not an easy thing to do: in C++17 you might be able to do something like

```
sizeof(map) + map.size() * sizeof(typename map::node_type);
```

to give you a rough guess, but really it will depend on the implementation details of your standard library.

Answer (score 1):

`std::map` defines the following methods

[**max_size()**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/max_size)

> Returns the maximum number of elements the container is able to hold due to system or library implementation limitations

[**size()**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/size)

> Returns the number of elements in the container

So, the following calculation will give you a good **approximation** of the actual size of the map in **bytes** (Given that the Key and Value types are structs of primitive types):

```
sizeof(mymap) + mymap.size() * (sizeof(decltype(mymap)::key_type) + sizeof(decltype(mymap)::mapped_type))
```

Comment: `the following calculation will give you the actual size of the map in bytes ` - I really doubt that it will. IIRC Map is often implemented as a **tree**, so you will have **at least** log(N) pointer overhead

Comment: @quetzalcoatl, you are 100% correct. I fixed my mistake to explicitly state that this is an approximation!