# Is there a way to declare a C++ protected variable from outside it's class?

Tags: c++, class, variables, protected

```
class A {
public:
    A();
    int get();
    void set();
};

protected int A::var;
```

seems like it would work. However, it "expects an unqualified-id before protected". What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How would the compiler know how much space to allocate for instances of the class? Consider

```
A foo;
protected int A::var;
A bar;
```

How would the compiler know to allocate space for `var` when it allocated `foo`? The first and second lines could even be in different translation units.

So, no, it's not possible because it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 6):

In simple words, No it is not possible.

in complex words, It is not possible because the standard allows the keyword and access specifier `protected` to be used only inside the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do *exactly* what you want (as others have said), but there are "hacks" around this if you just don't want to reveal `protected`/`private` members to users of your class.  You can create a `PrivateBase` and `PublicBase` class, and then a third class that uses multiple inheritance or composition of the two former classes.  Typically, this is done because you want to distribute a header file but you don't want to reveal all your private members.

[Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4619846/277718) of such.  I believe Scott Meyers also has an example in one of his books.  It's a lot more work and makes maintenance on your end a lot more complex, so keep that in mind.